# saga_cmd option for mosaiking tiles

Tags: saga

I am looking for an example of how to mosaik DEMs together using the SAGA command line.  Specifically, how to indicate the list of DEMs that you want to merge.

I found

```
saga_cmd grid_tools 3 -GRIDS <str> [-TYPE <str>] [-INTERPOL <str>] [-OVERLAP <str>] [-BLEND_DIST <str>] [-MATCH <str>] [-TARGET_DEFINITION <str>] [-TARGET_USER_XMIN <str>] [-TARGET_USER_XMAX <str>] [-TARGET_USER_YMIN <str>] [-TARGET_USER_YMAX <str>] [-TARGET_USER_SIZE <str>] [-TARGET_USER_FITS <str>] [-TARGET_TEMPLATE <str>] [-TARGET_OUT_GRID <str>]
```

however cannot figure out how to give the list of filenames

I tried

```
saga_cmd grid_tools 3 -GRIDS ["R1.tif", "R2.tif", "R3.tif"] -TARGET_OUT_GRID "test.sdat"
```

but this gives the error `zsh: bad pattern: [R1.tif,`

I have called the module from within QGIS to try copy that formatting, however that is not working (QGIS isn't working properly right now)

Comment: You specifically want to use the SAGA command line or using pyqgis is fine too ?

Comment: @wanderzen saga_cmd is all I have working reliably at the moment

Comment: Are the 'Processing Saga NextGen Provider' AND 'SAGA GIS provider' installed and checked within your Plugins Repository ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried separating them by ;?

```
saga_cmd grid_tools 3 -GRIDS "R1.tif;R2.tif;R3.tif" -TARGET_OUT_GRID "test.sdat"
```

[image]

Image and documentation found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/Command_Line_Scripting/).

Comment: I had tried ; instead of , but I had the format wrong with brackets and quotes around each file.